# Splitting a string with regular expressions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am in need of a regular expression that I can use to examine a string and return specific items when I do a RegEx.Split() in .NET. I've been trying to do this on my own, but I can never seem to get what I need, and the results never make any sense. Obviously I do not have a good handle on writing regular expressions.

So here is the string...

```
"%date - %-5level - [%thread] - %logger - %message - %exception%newline"
```

I essentially want to be returned an array that looks like the following:

```
"date"
"-5level"
"thread"
"logger"
"message"
"exception"
"newline"
```

The following code is close, but not quite.

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"\W+");
string[] s = exp.Split(@"%date - %-5level - [%thread] - %logger - %message - %exception%newline");
```

I get the following:

```
""
"date"
"5level"
"thread"
"logger"
"message"
"exception"
"newline"
```

For some reason, I have an empty string as the first index, and the 3rd index is missing the "-". I assume because it is not a part of a "word".

The "-" aside for the moment, I then want to split "5level" into an array:

```
"5"
"level"
```

I experimented with this:

```
Regex exp2 = new Regex(@"(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
string[] s2 = exp2.Split("5level");
```

But, it returns 2 indexes with empty strings in addition to the split items I want like so:

```
""
"5"
"level"
""
```

I'm stumped on how to format the expression to give me what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it would be polite of you to learn how to correctly use markdown so that others don't have to reformat your post. Take a look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This was my first time posting and I will keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `Regex.Split`, it might be easier to match the tokens you need:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"%([\w\-]+)");
string[] words = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Split may add empty matches, as you've witnessed, that will have to be filtered out.

Comment: By the way - doing a split to `\W+` is pretty much the anti-pattern to matching `\w+`. Oh, and in this case, the regex works pretty much the same without the `%` sign - you may need it depending on the input format, which wasn't specified.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I studied your expression to understand its logic. Thanks for the advice on using the MatchCollection. I wasn't even aware of that collection type.

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing this is to use `Named Capturing Groups` from [RegEx](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html) engine and to filter out any empty matches in the `Linq` query.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"%(?<SomeName>[\w\-]+)");
string[] words = matches.Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Length > 0 ).Select(m => m.Groups["SomeName"].Value).ToArray();
```